# Android Java: Add ImageView to TableRow without changing row size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, grid, tablerow

What I want to do is be able to insert a new ImageView into a LinearLayout which is inside a TableRow, without adjusting the size of the table row. My code is below.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addToGrid(7,7);
}

private void addToGrid(int x,int y)
{
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    TableRow row=(TableRow)table.getChildAt(x);
    LinearLayout box=(LinearLayout)row.getChildAt(y);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.location);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
    iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    box.addView(iv);
}
```

What I want is the following(but with the missing ImageView):

[image]

What I am getting is this:

[image]

Although I can't show the entire layout file as it is far too large, it goes like this in general:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/table">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="14">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border" />
```

Note that I am adding the ImageView(the map icon) to one of the Linearlayouts.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see two ways of accomplish this: intead of match parent in table row use specific values or use for a LinearLayouts and imageViews wrap_content

Comment: The images are missing

Comment: @piotrek I tried both ways neither worked. rafraph it might just be your browser, works fine on mine and my friends

Comment: Using GridLayout instead of TableLayout may help.